# The Best Day of the Week

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, poetry

To speak beneath the somber air

Oh, where the cattle meet!

To find a belle to stay awhile

And linger as we eat

To kill a mate, two may suffice;

And let us acquiesce

To making war with all of them

Before you take your rest.

---

Hint #1:

> Let me make your journey shorter! Try to think below the border...

Hint #2:

> Mairzy doats and dozy doats and liddle lamzy divey...

Comment: Didn't Rebecca Black say Friday was the best day? :-)

Comment: Indeed she did. She got down on Friday.

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I've been staring at this for too long. I'm not even sure I'm on the right track but I figured I'd take a stab. Maybe it'll help someone else?

> To speak beneath the somber air **Thursday** (speak beneath... thunder?)
>  Oh, where the cattle meet! 
>  To find a belle to stay awhile **Friday** (lover of odin)
>  And linger as we eat 
>  To kill a mate, two may suffice; **Wednesday** (i'm sure odin killed many)
>  And let us acquiesce **Monday** (resigned to go to work)
>  Before you take your rest. **Saturday** (*before* day of rest) 
>  To making war with all of them. **Tuesday** (god of war)
>  So far I'm leaning towards **Sunday** but I haven't figured out all the phrases or if parts of phrases are connected and so forth.

Comment: You’re on the right track, but there is much more to unpack :)

Comment: You just can't stop rhyming, can you? :)

Comment: I could if I wanted but that’d probably suck. My wife even hates that I rhyme when we...uh, make dinner.

Comment: Ride in a fire truck, clearly.